# IF ELSE statements to update table in sql procedure does not work

Tags: sql, sql-update, procedure, sqlanywhere

I have a table called *Employees* and need to update the SalaryId of the Employee by 1 if *1* is inputed and decrease it by -1 in case -1 is inputed. 
I think my approach has totally wrong logic, but I cannot find
what I wanna do although I hav been searching for a while. Can someone assist me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "dba"."updatePosition"(IN rating int, @PersonalID int )
AS BEGIN
   IF rating = 1 
     UPDATE dba.Employees
      IF (dba.Employees.SalaryId  > 1 && dba.Employees.SalaryId < 7)

      SET dba.Employees.SalaryId = dba.Employees.SalaryId  + 1
      WHERE dba.Employees.PersonalID = @PersonalID

   ELSEIF rating = -1
   UPDATE dba.Employees
   SET dba.Employees.SalaryId  = dba.Employees.SalaryId  - 1
        IF dba.Employees.SalaryId  < 1
           dba.Employees.SalaryId  = 1
        IF dba.Employees.SalaryId  > 7
           dba.Employees.SalaryId = 7
        WHERE dba.Employees.PersonalID = @PersonalID
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
 UPDATE dba.Employees
  IF (dba.Employees.SalaryId  > 1 && dba.Employees.SalaryId < 7)

  SET dba.Employees.SalaryId = dba.Employees.SalaryId  + 1
  WHERE dba.Employees.PersonalID = @PersonalID
```

Perhaps you want:

```
UPDATE dba.Employees
  SET dba.Employees.SalaryId = dba.Employees.SalaryId  + 1
  WHERE dba.Employees.PersonalID = @PersonalID AND
        dba.Employees.SalaryId  > 1 AND
        dba.Employees.SalaryId < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wildly mixing procedural code (`IF`) and SQL code (`UPDATE`, `WHERE`)...

I can imagine you're after something like that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "dba"."updatePosition"(IN @Rating int,
                                       IN @PersonalID int)
AS
BEGIN
  IF abs(@Rating) = 1 THEN
    UPDATE dba.Employees
           SET SalaryId + @Rating
           WHERE PersonalID = @PersonalID
                 AND SalaryId + @Rating >= 1
                 AND SalaryId + @Rating <= 7;
  END IF;
END;
```

It increases or decreases -- depending on the sign of `@Rating` -- the `SalaryId` of the employee identified by `@PersonalID` by `1`, if that change doesn't cause the `SalaryId` to drop below `1` or raise above `7` -- the checks for that belong in the `WHERE` clause an not in `IF`s spread anywhere in the `UPDATE` statement. To check that only steps of `-1` or `1` are possible, the `UPDATE` is wrapped in an `IF`, that is only entered, when the absolute value of `@Rating` equals `1`. You can also remove the `IF`, if you want to allow more than `1` step at once.